# Couldn't see other drive on ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, drive

I have a desktop with two drives, an SSD and an HDD. I have installed ubuntu desktop 12.04 on SSD. However, when I login, I couldn't see HDD drive. What steps should I follow? How should I format HDD and use it while my OS is on SSD. I am also open any recommendation to manage the drives in most efficient way (e.g. where to use HDD and where I need SSD most. Initially, boot time of OS seems quite important to me, so the OS is on SSD.) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four phases to install a new hard drive. Determine, partition, format and mount.

- First determine which drive you work on:

  `sudo lshw -C disk`

  If it is the second disk you install, it should be represented as `/dev/sdb`. So, I will continue the answer with `/dev/sdb`.
- Then, partition the disk with either `gparted` or `fdisk`.
- Format the partition. You can again use `gparted` for this purpose. If you prefer the command line, here is the your command:

  `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1`
- Now, as last action, mount the partition:

  1. Open `/etc/fstab` file with your favourite editor:

     `sudo vim /etc/fstab`
  2. Add this line to the end of the file:

     `/dev/sdb1    /media/mydrive1   ext4    defaults     0        2`

For a full guide, refer to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive).

Answer (score 1):

Type in the terminal

```
ls /dev/ | grep sd
```

to list your hard drives. sda should be your primary drive and sdb should be your secondary drive, in your case the HDD. The numbers on the end refers to partitions (for example /dev/sda0 refers to the first partition on the primary hard disk). 
If the sdb drive doesn't show up, the OS recognize it. If it shows up, add the drive into the /etc/fstab file. Here you got the [link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.1/chapter08/fstab.html) with the instructions.
You should add something like this

```
/dev/sdb0 /media <file system type (ext4, ntfs....)> defaults 0 0
```